# Autocompletion of usernames in comments sometimes does not display all of the characters

Tags: bug, comments

I noticed during a conversation with [User ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟッ](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/59761) under a post of mine that the last character `ッ` does not appear in the autocompletion when I start my comment with `@` to ping them. Most probably this is because `ッ` doesn't come from a "standard" Roman script? I believe the pings *are* going through, but the best person to confirm or deny this would be ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟッ.

One can test this by picking any comment by ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟッ from their [activity page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/59761?tab=activity&sort=comments) to reply to. (Of course, there is no need to actually *post* a comment to test this, so I'm not inviting spam to rain down on them. I hope.)

Can the username autocomplete please be made to pick up *all* the characters?

Comment: Works for me:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbbki.png.  Do you explicitly override sites from setting their own fonts?  (Also for the reference this is the small Japanese character tsu (ッ) which would be hard to type out if you didn't have an IME or had it in your paste buffer.

Comment: @Makoto I see! I haven’t configured such a setting manually anywhere, so I’m not sure… This is what I see on Safari on iOS 14.7.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zVQr.png. (I’m using the site in the responsive design setting.)

Comment: I'll add that I am getting the proper autocompletion for [User 絢瀬絵里](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/7866), so I'm not sure why there's an issue only with the Japanese character in ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟッ.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the pings do come to me. It *is* pretty weird though, how the last character is left off when someone is trying to @ me (in a posts comments). Nonetheless, I do get the ping, so this ain't much of an issue.

This is especially weird because when I was talking with user @Makoto on MSE, the ッ is there. And when I'm in chat, and get pinged, it's there is well ([here is an example conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/chat-with-peilonrayz)). Kinda weird for it to just not show up on A&M.

I do not participate on *too many* SE sites, and I've only noticed this on A&M. I do see the ッ on other Stack Exchange networks though.

I doubt this is from it being a special character,since every part of my username is.

[image]

Comment: Since you're currently pingable in the [chat], I tested the autocompletion there, and it shows your full username with the final *tsu* character for me, as you mentioned. But on the main and meta sites, I'm not seeing the final character in the autocompletion. Huh!